# What am I doing wrong to adjust my view in iOS when resigning keyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, textfield, keyboard-events

I have 6 Textfields in my viewController. 2 on the first row, 1 on the second, 1 on the third and 2 on the last row. The textfields work fine as far as typing into it. I just have issues scrolling the view up and down when the keyboard appears. The view scrolls up fine but when I "resign responder", ***the view scrolls down but scrolls down too much.***  e.g. if the view moved up by y amount, once I resign responder, the view would move down a value greater than y.

I have the following code set up (I've provided extra code just in case but I believe the problem is in setViewMovedUp method, but I may be wrong):

Keyboard showing:

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)sender {
// Animate the current view out of the way
NSDictionary* info = [sender userInfo];
kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

if (!didViewMove) {

    didViewMove = YES;

    if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:YES];

    }
    else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
    }
}
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide {

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, _top, 320, self.view.frame.size.height);
}];
return;

didViewMove = NO;

if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
{
    [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
}
else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
{
    [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
}
}
```

Adjusting the View

```
 -(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; // slide up the view

int desiredHeight = (480 - kbSize.height) / 2;
int requiredHeightAdjustment;

if (didViewMove) {
    requiredHeightAdjustment = abs(desiredHeight - (self.view.frame.origin.y + activeField.frame.origin.y));
} else {
    requiredHeightAdjustment = abs(desiredHeight - (activeField.frame.origin.y ));
 //   requiredHeightAdjustment = abs(desiredHeight - (self.view.frame.origin.y + activeField.frame.origin.y));
}


CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

if (movedUp)
{
    // 1. move the view's origin up so that the text field that will be hidden come above the keyboard
    // 2. increase the size of the view so that the area behind the keyboard is covered up.
    rect.origin.y -= requiredHeightAdjustment;
   rect.size.height += requiredHeightAdjustment;

}
else
{
    // revert back to the normal state.
      rect.origin.y += requiredHeightAdjustment;
 rect.size.height -= requiredHeightAdjustment;
}
self.view.frame = rect;

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Resigning Responder

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if ([_cardnumbertext isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != _cardnumbertext) {
    [_cardnumbertext resignFirstResponder];
}
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

UITouch *touch1 = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if ([_salesamounttext isFirstResponder] && [touch1 view] != _salesamounttext) {
    [_salesamounttext resignFirstResponder];
}
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

UITouch *touch2 = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if ([_referencetext isFirstResponder] && [touch2 view] != _referencetext) {
    [_referencetext resignFirstResponder];
}
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

UITouch *touch3 = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if ([_datetext isFirstResponder] && [touch3 view] != _datetext) {
    [_datetext resignFirstResponder];
}
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

UITouch *touch4 = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if ([_timetext isFirstResponder] && [touch4 view] != _timetext) {
    [_timetext resignFirstResponder];
}
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

UITouch *touch5 = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if ([_reasontext isFirstResponder] && [touch5 view] != _reasontext) {
    [_reasontext resignFirstResponder];
}
[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

and lastly, setting up active fields

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
previousField = activeField;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to use `UIScrollView` and just scroll it.(and if you don't want user to scroll it just disallow scrolling).

Comment: in `keyboardWillHide` method you have return on second line ,
it will never go through your `if-else` statements.

Comment: onkeyboard hide.. set the scrollView content offset to (0,0).

Also you dont need to do so much logics to scroll up and down.

look into this how to properly manage keyboard functionality with input fields

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

Comment: @faiziii Does this mean I have to change my view into a UIScrollView??

Answer (score 2):

What I do is to make the final amount that I scroll up an instance variable. I also save the duration and timing curve settings from the keyboard notification.

Then, when the user finishes editing and I get notified that the keyboard is going away, I can just move my view by the reverse of the saved amount that I moved the view up in the first place.

I suggest using that approach.

I have a sample project on github that documents this approach in detail:

[RandomBlobs project on github](https://github.com/DuncanMC/RandomBlobs)

Look in the README for a section titled "Miscellaneous techniques". Look for a link "Sliding your views to make room for the keyboard". It is working code using the technique I describe above.

Comment: Why did you down-vote my answer? I am suggesting a tried-and-true approach that works well.

Comment: Sorry, It might've been a misclick.