# What is a good practice to adjust/moving view up and down when keyboard is shown, without using a scroll view(iOS)?

Tags: ios, view, uitextfield, keyboard-events, uikeyboard

What is a good practice/way to adjust/moving view up and down when keyboard is shown, without using a scroll view?

I've posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512837/what-am-i-doing-wrong-to-adjust-my-view-in-ios-when-resigning-keyboards/22513454?noredirect=1#22513454) because my method was not working properly, and I desperately need a method that is safe and works.

Comment: Why must the answer not include a scroll view, since that's the (Apple) [recommended](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) way? I use scroll views and don't have any problems, though Apple's sample code is somewhat incomplete.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I have written and made most of my app already and all the objects are in a view rather than scroll view. I am afraid that it may alter things if I move it over to a scroll view

Comment: In Interface Builder, in the Document Outline panel, expand the UIView, select all the items you want to embed in the scroll view, then pick Editor->Embed In->Scroll View from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried as like below?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSNotificationCenter * center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidAppear) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillDisAppear) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

-(void)keyboardDidAppear
{
    CGRect frame = view.frame;

    frame.origin.y -= 214.0;

    view.frame = frame;
}

-(void)keyboardWillDisAppear
{
    CGRect frame = view.frame;

    frame.origin.y += 214.0;

    view.frame = frame;
}
```